# Gulp Browsersync is not working for scripts.js file

Tags: node.js, webpack, browser-sync

I am new to Gulp watch and I'm facing the issue of Browsersync that is only refreshed for first time only when I run the "gulp watch" command and it only works for HTML,CSS files but not for scripts.js files.
I made this change on glop-watcher/index file

```
        function onChange() {
          console.log("onChange running: ", running); // custom changing
        if (running) {
          if (opt.queue) {
            queued = true;
          }
          // custom changing
          setTimeout(() => {
         runComplete({msg: "custom code is working"});
            }, 2000);
          return;
       }
```

now its refreshed the HTML,CSS file but still not working for scripts.js file at all even if refresh manually. Please help 
Here is my gulpfile.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
settings = require('./settings'),
webpack = require('webpack'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
rgba = require('postcss-hexrgba'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
mixins = require('postcss-mixins'),
colorFunctions = require('postcss-color-function');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'css/style.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, mixins, cssvars, nested, rgba, colorFunctions, autoprefixer]))
    .on('error', (error) => console.log(error.toString()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.themeLocation));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
  webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    }

    console.log(stats.toString());
    callback();
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    proxy: settings.urlToPreview,
    ghostMode: false
  });

  gulp.watch('./**/*.php', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
  gulp.watch(settings.themeLocation + 'css/**/*.css', gulp.parallel('waitForStyles'));
  gulp.watch([settings.themeLocation + 'js/modules/*.js', settings.themeLocation + 'js/scripts.js'], gulp.parallel('waitForScripts'));
});

gulp.task('waitForStyles', gulp.series('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'style.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}))

gulp.task('waitForScripts', gulp.series('scripts', function(cb) {
  browserSync.reload();
  cb()
}))
```

Comment: PLEASE SOMEONE HELP.... I'm stuck on this problem since 12 days from now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after 2 weeks of drilling into gulp I found the problem and solution too.

Here is the path of my .js files that gulp is watching

**" .\myProject\wp-content\themes\myProject-theme\js "**

but for gulp watch the path should be like this

**" ./wp-content/themes/myProject-theme/js/*.js "**

It does not include the main folder name/ root folder name. In my case the root folder where all my wordpress files lives is " myProject " and I mistakenly wrote it in gulp path that trouble me so much.

So be sure about your paths and also add this in onChange() function of glop-watcher/index file that is in the node_modules folder.

```
 function onChange() {
      console.log("onChange running: ", running);
    if (running) {
      if (opt.queue) {
        queued = true;
      }
      // Add this code
      setTimeout(() => {
     runComplete({msg: "custom code is working"});
        }, 2000);
      return;
   }
```